# Plotting Multiple Groupedby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Make a plot for a large data set that I want to plot with Pandas groupby.

The groupby is two layers. One is numeric (desired x-axis) and one is categorical (wanting to make this different boxes on a stacked bar chart. I sum the values of the groups and that will create my y_axis.

So I construct the following group by dataframe.

```
     import pandas as pd
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     data= pd.DataFrame()

     data['x_axis'] = [1,1,2,2]
     data['category'] = ['a','b','a','b']
     data['y_value'] = [10,15,20,30]

     data = data.groupby(['x_axis','category']).sum()
     data.reset_index(inplace = True)


     data.plot.bar(x = 'x_axis', y= 'y_value', stacked = True)
     plt.show()
```

This results in the following

```
    numeric_x_axis   category  sum_value
            1            a         10
                         b         15
            2            a         20
                         b         30
```

Therefore the desires chart would have a stacked bar chart with a x axis of (1,2) and stacked bars for a and b with the sum value as the y axis value.

However the chart appear with multiple repeat x_axis values.

Comment: What exactly is the problem or question? Did you try to make that chart? If so, show us the code and explicitely state the problem. If not, try it first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use `groupby`? Based on your description, it seems as though you would be better served by `pivot`.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

data['x_axis'] = [1,1,2,2]
data['category'] = ['a','b','a','b']
data['y_value'] = [10,15,20,30]

pivoted_data = data.pivot('x_axis', 'category')
pivoted_data.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Note, the pivoted dataframe looks like

```
In [2]: pivoted_data
Out[2]: 
         y_value    
category       a   b
x_axis              
1             10  15
2             20  30
```